# May I ask a question about logic written in the Prolog language on CS.SE?

Tags: discussion

Good morning!

I'm learning logic through Prolog and I was wondering how to manage a Prolog resolution. I have an exercise to run by hand and to verify on a compiler but I don't know if Computer Science.SE is the right place to ask... I already asked it on Stack Overflow but didn't had any answers... I am wondering if CS.SE is a better place as far as some questions are asked about logic and get answers. Yet, as I said, it's learning logic through the Prolog language...

If you have any advice, I would be glad to hear them!

Comment: I'm torn. Logic questions are ontopic, Prolog programming questions are offtopic. If you can make it a logic question expressed using Prolog syntax, I guess it's fine.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34205740) appears to be the question under discussion.

Comment: If the question linked by Arthur is indeed the question at stake, I'd say it is not a good fit for this SE.